# constraining type in Seq.scan

Tags: f#

I am not sure why this happens

```
   //fine, type of xs is Set<int>
   let e = Seq.scan (fun xs         x -> Set.add x xs) Set.empty [1..2]  

   //bad, type of xs is Set<obj>,  no type check no good
   let e = Seq.scan (fun(xs:Set<_>) x -> Set.add x xs) Set.empty [1..2]
```

Must be my eyes but what gives ?

Comment: It's `Set<int>` for me in both cases.

Comment: that is odd... indeed when I paste it in another file, i can not reproduce. it must have to do with opening module (?). HOLD FIRE

Comment: So indeed some other library in a namespace I opened redefined Set<_>.  Set.add refered to the FSharp Set<_>, the good one, while Set<_> refered to the evil one !

Comment: thks daniel. domo arigato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As precised in the comment, I was **opening the namespace** of some other library further up in my file.

Being a C# library, it **redefines** its own `Set` (poor folks)

Doing so, writing `Set<_>` induced the compiler in picking up their version, whilst `Set.add` still refered to the trusted FSharp `Set<_>`.

Eventually, the two came in brutal head to head conflict with each other.